# "the boy Sam and Tom" or "the boys Sam and Tom"?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

I do not know the grammatical terms for this kind of usage.  I can only give an example.  I want to describe two boys called Sam and Tom.  Of course I can just say

> Sam and Tom are nice.

But I want to be a bit clear about their gender.  But instead of the a bit verbose

> The boy Sam and the boy Tom are nice.

I would like to factor out *the boy*.  Then I am not sure the result would be which one of the following three:

> The boy Sam and Tom is nice.
>
> The boy Sam and Tom are nice.
>
> The boys Sam and Tom are nice.

An answer that comes with the grammatical terms for such usage will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too basic for ELU, and should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do not see "too basic for ELU" listed in the out-of-scope topics in the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, I could have included "imho" in that comment (in *all* my comments, come to that). But let's face it, no native speaker would ever ask your question, and it's unlikely many of ELU's target audience [linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would find anything remotely interesting in the kind of answers that would be appropriate. Just out of interest, do you have some *objection* to the idea that this should have been asked originally (or should now be migrated) to ELL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of omitting parts of a sentence because they are understood within the context is called [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29). But this is not strictly ellipsis because you are actually changing what is left after omitting the second "the boy".

> The boy Sam and the boy Tom are nice.

Here is it clear that both are boys because both Sam and Tom are individually described as a "boy".

> The boy Sam and Tom are nice.

Because *boy* is singular, here only Sam is definitely described as a boy. Tom could be Thomasina; or a man; or another boy: there's no way to know for certain.

The only way to ensure that Sam and Tom are both boys is to explicitly say that they are:

> The boys Sam and Tom are nice.

This sort of "factoring out" is a form of [Coordination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_%28linguistics%29).